# Campagnolo crank spider inter-compatibility between 'standard' and 'compact' chainrings

Tags: chainring, campagnolo, compact-crankset

Will a Campagnolo Athena (2014) crank spider and crank arm from a 'standard' chainring setup of 39/53 accommodate 'compact' chainrings of 34/50, also Campagnolo Athena (2014)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, compact chainrings have 110 BCD (bolt circle diameter) while standard chainrings have 135 BCD.